# HTML5 figure element: is there a javascript library to emulate this element for "old" browser?

Tags: iphone, ios, html, figure

I'm using figure element in an UIWebView.
On IOS5.0 and later, the figure is rendered correctly...
On iOS4.3 the rendering is not correct.

Is there a way to emulate  element with a javascript library ?

Comment: Do you mean that Mobile Safari did not have default styling for `<figure>` in 4.3? And if so, can't you write your own CSS for it?

Comment: @Matijs: I think you are right...and my question is not correct. In fact, the figure element is rendered but no default styling is applied... I will try to add a "default style" to this figure element.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution tx Matijs remark.
After adding this CSS, it works now!

```
figure {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  display: block;
}
```